# Is it possible to set colors per single event within events: [] in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/.

I am building an `events: []` list using PHP:

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar', 'user', 'pass');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM holidays");

    $stmt->execute();

    $return_array = array();
    $event_array;

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $event_array = array();

          $event_array['id'] = $row['id'];
          $event_array['title'] = $row['id'] . " - " . $row['forename'] . " " . $row['surname'];
          $event_array['start'] = $row['start'];
          $event_array['end'] = $row['end'];
          $event_array['allDay'] = true;

          // what I want to be able to do
          if ($row['department'] == 'UK') { $event_array['color'] = '#000000'; };
          if ($row['department'] == 'US') { $event_array['color'] = '#000000'; };
          else { $event_array['color'] = '#000000'; };

          array_push($return_array, $event_array);
        }

    echo json_encode($return_array);
?>
```

I would like to know if it's possible to color each individual event within the array. I see at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/ it is possible to set colors but these are set on the whole `eventSources: []` rather than a color that can change per event in the same `eventSource`.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: event also supports using `className`, apply a class to the event, and use CSS

Comment: perhaps, as suggested by MLeFevre, use jQuery.addClass() prototype and toggle classes where needed?

Comment: You can also accomplish alot more by using a `className` rather than their `color` value, for example http://i.imgur.com/lDH5R2k.png

Comment: @MLeFevre Are you able to provide an example as an answer?

Comment: @user3838132 You're already creating an event array, but not assigning a `className` to any of them. If you add another row, `$event_array['className'] = 'amazing_event';` for example, then a css rule like `.amazing_event { background-color:purple;}` does that work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your JS is correctly displaying your created json array, can't tell without your js code.

There's [an attribute you can use](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/) called `className`, which will specify the class added to each event.

In your example you should be able to do something like:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $event_array = array();

      $event_array['id'] = $row['id'];
      $event_array['title'] = $row['id'] . " - " . $row['forename'] . " " . $row['surname'];
      $event_array['start'] = $row['start'];
      $event_array['end'] = $row['end'];
      $event_array['allDay'] = true;

      // Apply a different class depending on the department
      if ($row['department'] == 'UK') { 
          $event_array['className'] = 'uk_event'; 
      } else if ($row['department'] == 'US') { 
          $event_array['className'] = 'us_event'; 
      } else { 
          $event_array['className'] = 'general_event'; 
      };

      array_push($return_array, $event_array);
}
```

Then on the page where you display your calendar, you can use some CSS to style those rules, for example:

```
.uk_event {
    background-color:blue;
}

.us_event {
    background-color:red;
}

.general_event {
    background-color:black;
}
```

UK events should be coloured blue, US events coloured red etc...

looking at a calendar I made ages ago with FullCalendar, I had to be more specific and apply style changes to the child div:

```
 .uk_event div {
     background-color:blue;
 }
```

Not sure if that's necessary now, or why I did it like that back then. Could be a version difference thing, i'm not sure, try both and see if either work.

That's the general idea of how to do it anyway.